How to calculate daily in out working hours
I have a table that stores daily in-out employee-wise data. I will share one employee's data below.
NO, EMP ID      date                IN-OUT
1   MS00093 12-Jun-24 10:43:27 AM   0
2   MS00093 12-Jun-24 10:50:18 AM   1
3   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:20:08 PM    1
4   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:20:27 PM    0
5   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:21:08 PM    1
6   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:21:16 PM    0
7   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:30:13 PM    1
8   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:56:05 PM    0
9   MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:38:34 PM    1
10  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:38:34 PM    1
11  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:40:21 PM    0
12  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:40:21 PM    0
13  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:42:14 PM    1
14  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:42:14 PM    1
15  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:42:40 PM    1
16  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:08:05 PM    0
17  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:08:05 PM    0
18  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:10:22 PM    1
19  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:12:40 PM    1
20  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:15:27 PM    0
21  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:36:38 PM    0
22  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:38:36 PM    1
23  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:38:55 PM    1
24  MS00093 12-Jun-24 4:29:57 PM    1
25  MS00093 12-Jun-24 5:12:17 PM    1

In the provided data, "0" represents the time an employee checked IN and "1" represents the time they checked OUT. To calculate the sum of the last check-in and the first check-out, review rows 1 -2,4-5,8-9,12 -13,17-18,21-22 for accurate check-in and check-out times. If an employee's data includes multiple entries, consider the last check-in, as seen in rows 12, 17, and 21. For multiple check-outs, consider the first check-in, such as in rows 2, 9, 13, 18, and 22. Once this is verified, calculate the total hours worked.
expected Output
NO  EMP ID    DATE                IN-OUT sum of Hour
1   MS00093 12-Jun-24 10:43:27 AM   0   06 mi 51 sec
2   MS00093 12-Jun-24 10:50:18 AM   1   
3   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:20:08 PM    1   
4   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:20:27 PM    0   41 sec
5   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:21:08 PM    1   
6   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:21:16 PM    0   08 mi 57sec
7   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:30:13 PM    1   
8   MS00093 12-Jun-24 1:56:05 PM    0   42 mi 29sec
9   MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:38:34 PM    1   
10  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:38:34 PM    1   
11  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:40:21 PM    0   
12  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:40:21 PM    0   01mi 53 sec
13  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:42:14 PM    1   
14  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:42:14 PM    1   
15  MS00093 12-Jun-24 2:42:40 PM    1   
16  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:08:05 PM    0   
17  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:08:05 PM    0   2.17 sec
18  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:10:22 PM    1   
19  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:12:40 PM    1   
20  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:15:27 PM    0   
21  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:36:38 PM    0   2 sec
22  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:38:36 PM    1   
23  MS00093 12-Jun-24 3:38:55 PM    1   
24  MS00093 12-Jun-24 4:29:57 PM    1   
25  MS00093 12-Jun-24 5:12:17 PM    1   

i'm making a script using lag and lead functions, but I'm not getting the desired output.
select SZEMPID,SZDT,SZINOUT,LAG_DAY from (
select a.*, lag(SZINOUT) over( order by SZDT) lag_day from temp_pmp a)
where SZINOUT <>LAG_DAY ;


Do you still run Oracle 11g? It is out of support for ages?

You can use SQL for Pattern Matching:
WITH t as (
   select NO, EMP_ID, check_DATE, last_check_in, first_check_out
   from EMP
   MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
      PARTITION BY EMP_ID
      ORDER BY NO -- or ORDER BY check_DATE
      MEASURES 
         LAST(check_in.check_DATE) as last_check_in,
         FIRST(check_out.check_DATE) as first_check_out
      ALL ROWS PER MATCH
      PATTERN (check_in+ check_out+)
      DEFINE 
         check_in AS IN_OUT = 0,
         check_out AS IN_OUT = 1
   )
select NO, EMP_ID, check_DATE, (first_check_out - last_check_in) * 24 as sum_of_Hour
from t;

(not tested)

The OP has tagged the question with Oracle11. MATCH_RECOGNIZE was not introduced until Oracle 12.

For each IN row followed by an OUT row, you want the time difference of the two rows.
SELECT 
  no, emp_id, dt, in_out,
  case when in_out = 0 and lead(in_out) over (partition by emp_id order by dt, no) = 1 then 
    lead(dt) over (partition by emp_id order by dt, no) - dt
  end as duration
from mytable
order by emp_id, dt, no;

If the date column is a TIMESTAMP actually, you will get an interval. If it is a DATE you will get the difference in days (or a fraction of a day). You can always cast a date to timestamp or vice versa, if you want to, of course.

I have one method using joins. You can also do it with lag but you need to take care in case of date changes with no check-out end of day.
I am breaking into 2 stages -
create table temp as
select a.in_out as checkin,b.in_out as checkout,b.date as checkout_time,a.date as checkin_time from (select * from table where in_out=0) a
inner join (select * from table where in_out=1) b on a.emp=b.emp and cast(a.date as date)=cast(b.date as date) and a.date<b.date;

create table temp2 as
select checkin,checkout,checkout_time1,max(checkin_time) as checkin_time from (
select checkin,checkout,checkin_time,min(checkout_time) as checkout_time1
from temp group by 1,2,3)a
group by 1,2,3;

select sum(checout_time1-checkin_time1) as total_work from temp2 will give you the total hours.


"you need to take care in case of date changes with no check-out end of day." Why would that be a problem - if the user is not checked-out then they are still checked-in regardless of whether the time reaches midnight or not (some people may work night shifts or be on-call 24 hours a day).

Also, why create permanent tables for temporary data? Use WITH or nested sub-queries and you don't need temporary tables,

cast(a.date as date) is pointless - in Oracle, a DATE data-type always has a time component so using CAST does not remove the time component. You want to TRUNCate the date back to midnight if you want to compare by day.

@Mt0 - It depends on use case as both are possible. Employee might forget to checkout or the person might be on shift. I think the requester can take a call on that. If we have to consider irrespective of shift, we can remove the date=date condition in the join statement.
for 2nd comment, Yes, this can be done using with or temp table depending on preference.
For 3rd - It depends on the tool you are using. Cast in Netezza-sql converts datetime to time, and trunc is date_trunc in few tools. The functions may vary slightly depending on the tool.

It's not LAG that you have to use but FIRST_VALUE() to get the next OUT when the current row is a IN:
WITH DATA(emp_id, dat, in_out) as (
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 10:43:27', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 10:50:18', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 13:20:08', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 13:20:27', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 13:21:08', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 13:21:16', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 13:30:13', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 13:56:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 14:38:34', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 14:38:34', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 14:40:21', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 14:40:21', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 14:42:14', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 14:42:14', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 14:42:40', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 15:08:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 15:08:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 15:10:22', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 15:12:40', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 15:15:27', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 15:36:38', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 15:38:36', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 15:38:55', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 16:29:57', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'MS00093', to_date('2024-06-12 17:12:17', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY dat) AS rn,
    emp_id, dat, in_out,
    CASE in_out WHEN 0 THEN
        FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN in_out = 1 THEN dat END IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY dat
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    END AS next_out,
    NUMTODSINTERVAL(24 * CASE in_out WHEN 0 THEN
        first_value(case when in_out = 1 then dat END IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY dat
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) - dat
    END, 'HOUR') AS delta_time
FROM data d
ORDER BY dat
;

https://dbfiddle.uk/Th8RriDM
Note that SUM() of date interval is not yet available until 23, so in 11 you will have to sum before converting to interval and you should maybe also PARTITION BY emp_id and TRUNC(dat) to get pair of IN-OUT the same day if this is a requirement, but if overnight shifts are allowed it's ok to PARTITION only on emp_id.

i'm not sure for oracle but this is my best shot using MariaDB;
CREATE TABLE 
    `local_db`.`test_inout` (`NO` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `EMP_ID` VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL ,
    `DATE_REG` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    `IN_OUT` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `TIME_IN_SEC` UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL 
    PRIMARY KEY (`NO`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Now, i'll put rows; (dates are in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS because is more easy to handle)
INSERT INTO `test_inout` (`EMP_ID`, `DATE_REG`, `IN_OUT`) VALUES
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 10:43:27', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 10:50:18', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 13:20:08', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 13:20:27', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 13:21:08', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 13:21:16', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 13:30:13', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 13:56:05', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 14:38:34', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 14:38:34', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 14:40:21', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 14:40:21', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 14:42:14', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 14:42:14', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 14:42:40', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 15:08:05', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 15:08:05', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 15:10:22', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 15:12:40', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 15:15:27', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 15:36:38', 0),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 15:38:36', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 15:38:55', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 16:29:57', 1),
('MS00093', '2024-06-12 17:12:17', 1);

So, i'll fill("update") TIME_IN_SEC with time in seconds (you can convert it in  min-sec dividing by 60 or hours x2, etc). I'll put seconds because 'raw' data is better IMO. You can 'mask' seconds to any kind of date format in 1 step:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_inout AS
SELECT t1.NO, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.DATE_REG, t2.DATE_REG) AS TIME_IN_OUT
FROM `test_inout` t1
JOIN `test_inout` t2 ON t1.NO = t2.NO - 1
WHERE t1.IN_OUT = 0;

UPDATE test_inout 
JOIN temp_inout ON test_inout.NO = temp_inout.NO
SET test_inout.TIME_IN_OUT = temp_inout.TIME_IN_OUT;

If you example-data isn't a isolated table with only 'MS00093', and you're working on 'main' table (make a copy and test over copy ¬¬).
You can add 'AND t1.EMP_ID = t2.EMP_ID' to JOIN in temp table and add 'AND test_inout.EMP_ID = temp_inout.EMP_ID' in update statement;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_inout AS
SELECT t1.EMP_ID, t1.NO, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.DATE_REG, t2.DATE_REG) AS TIME_IN_OUT
FROM `test_inout` t1
JOIN `test_inout` t2 ON t1.NO = t2.NO - 1 AND t1.EMP_ID = t2.EMP_ID
WHERE t1.IN_OUT = 0;

UPDATE test_inout 
JOIN temp_inout ON test_inout.NO = temp_inout.NO AND test_inout.EMP_ID = temp_inout.EMP_ID
SET test_inout.TIME_IN_OUT = temp_inout.TIME_IN_OUT;

I know... Oracle isn't MariaDB and syntax isn't same but, you can use some AI to 'translate' it to Oracle.
I can't post any 'translation' because I would be breaking the rules about post AI-crap-code.
I hope, maybe, this clue can help you
